# Subtract two columns in a query for 2 given types, otherwise leave as is

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, self-join

```
CREATE TABLE #test (Type1 VARCHAR(10),NUM1 VARCHAR(10), Grp1 VARCHAR(10), Amt1 INT, Amt2 INT)

INSERT INTO #test
(
  Type1,
  NUM1,
  Grp1,
  Amt1,
  Amt2
)
VALUES
  ('CA',    'TIX_1',    'GG', 3, 5),
  ('PR',    'TIX_1',    'GG', 2, 1),
  ('PR',    'TIX_2',    'XX', 1, 5)
```

Let's say I have data in a table that looks like this:

```
Type1   NUM1    Grp1    Amt1    Amt2
CA      TIX_1   GG      3       5
PR      TIX_1   GG      2       1
PR      TIX_2   XX      1       5
```

For a given `NUM1` I will either have 2 `Type1` (CA, PR) or 1 `Typ1`, either CA or PR again.

Goal is for those NUM1's that have PR and CA record to do a simple subtraction, however if there is NUM1 with only one Type1 (either CA or PR) then leave as is

Goal:

```
NUM1    Grp1    Amt1    Amt2
TIX_1   GG      1       4
TIX_2   XX      1       5
```

I'm trying to do this with a FULL JOIN like so:

```
SELECT t1.NUM1,
       t1.Grp1,
       t1.Amt1 - t2.Amt1 AS X, --(CA - PR )
       t1.Amt2 - t2.Amt2 AS Y  --(CA - PR )
FROM #test t1 FULL JOIN #test t2 
     ON t1.NUM1=t2.NUM1 
     AND t1.Grp1=t2.Grp1 
     AND t2.Type1='PR'
WHERE t1.Type1='CA'
```

Result from above query:

```
 NUM1   Grp1    X   Y
 TIX_1  GG      1   4
```

For TIX_2 - there is only 1 `Type1 = PR`, so No data gets pulled up, but is there a way I can JOIN the data and subtract it to achieve my goal?

@NBK Edit

```
 NUM1   Grp1    X   Y
 TIX_1    GG    1   4
 TIX_1    GG    0   0
 TIX_2    XX    0   0
  NULL    NULL  NULL    NULL
```

Comment: the where condition excludes TIX_2 so remove it and see why you get

Comment: @nbk see edit.. the WHERE clause because I'm trying to Select for 'CA' and FULL JOIN 'PR'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great work on your Minimal Reproducible Example!

One approach, which works with this dataset, but may not work with a more complex dataset is a straight `group by` with a conditional sum e.g.

```
select min(Type1), NUM1, Grp1
    , case when min(Type1) = 'CA' then sum(Amt1 * case when Type1 = 'CA' then 1 else -1 end) else sum(Amt1) end
    , case when min(Type1) = 'CA' then sum(Amt2 * case when Type1 = 'CA' then 1 else -1 end) else sum(Amt2) end
from #test
group by NUM1, Grp1;
```

A more complex approach, which would work with a more complex dataset would use CTEs.

1. In the first `cte` get the count of rows per `NUM1`
2. Then in the second `cte` get a row number, and a conditional sum over `NUM1`. The row number allows us to then filter only the first row per `NUM1`. The conditional sum allows us to sum the amounts for a given `NUM1` only reversing `Type1='PA'` when there is more than one row for that `NUM1`.

```
with cte1 as (
    select *
        , count(*) over (partition by NUM1) Cnt
    from #test
), cte2 as (
    select Type1, NUM1, Grp1, Amt1, Amt2, rn
        , row_number() over (partition by NUM1 order by Type1) rn
        , sum(Amt1 * case when Type1 = 'CA' or Cnt = 1 then 1 else -1 end) over (partition by NUM1) Amt11
        , sum(Amt2 * case when Type1 = 'CA' or Cnt = 1 then 1 else -1 end) over (partition by NUM1) Amt22
    from cte1
)
select Type1, NUM1, Grp1, Amt11, Amt22
from cte2
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: @Koosh see the simplified form which may work.